# How can I import a .sql file into my Heroku postgres database?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, import

I have a backup sql file from another database that I want to import into Heroku's postgres database. How do you do that?

Comment: This solution will also be relevant for some people:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433414/heroku-database-restore-issue/42435490#42435490

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
heroku pg:psql --app YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE < updates.sql
```

And if you want to restore your production into staging (assuming both are heroku postgres DBs):

```
heroku pgbackups:restore YOUR_STAGING_DATABASE_NAME `heroku pgbackups:url --app YOUR_PRODUCTION_APP_NAME` --app YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME --confirm YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME
```

Make sure to preserve the special single quotes around `heroku pgbackups:url --app YOUR_PRODUCTION_APP_NAME`.

---

### HEROKU TOOLBELT UPDATE

Heroku has recently updated their toolbelt so the old commands are no longer valid (see [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mapping-pgbackups-commands) for more info). Below is the new version of the restore command.

```
heroku pg:backups restore \
  `heroku pg:backups public-url -a YOUR_PRODUCTION_APP_NAME` \
  YOUR_STAGING_DATABASE_NAME \
  --app YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME \
  --confirm YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME
```

Comment: In the first example, if you have more than 1 database on the app, you can specify the non-default (the one that doesn't use `DATABASE_URL`) by doing `heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN_URL --app YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE < updates.sql` as an example.  Of course, substitute your own db URL environment variable for the one that I put in this example.

Comment: Make sure you've already created a backup on heroku for the database you're looking to clone!

Comment: Doesn't this still require uploading to S3 or some local repository? How can one load a local sql dump to a heroku postgres DB?

Comment: For me,
heroku pg:psql --app APP_NAME < sales_purchase_backup.sql
, this failed first expecting amazon s3 url, but when I tried again it worked in Heroku CLI

Answer (score 33):

Making backup file:

```
pg_dump -U USERNAME DATABASE --no-owner --no-acl -f backup.sql
```

Restoring from sql file to heroku :

```
heroku pg:psql --app APPNAME < backup.sql
```

(Bonus) Deleting all tables from heroku app database (example):

```
heroku pg:reset --app APPNAME HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE
```

get DATABASE_URL from posgresql heroku panel (psql line)

Comment: Thanks! Everywhere else I looked indicated I had to upload to S3.

Comment: ---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.

Comment: I had to use the following command: pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump

Comment: Abel, is this the preferred method of backing up a database? What are the limitations?

Answer (score 2):

Load the SQL into a local Postgres instance and make sure it's correct. Then dump the data using the directions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Finally, upload the dump to a public web server (like S3) and restore to Heroku like this:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having a local database? I have a .sql file with sql statements. It has all the CREATE TABLES and insert datas. I just need a way to send that SQL into Postgres on Heroku.

Comment: Yes, you can use PgAdmin to connect remotely to your Heroku database and paste your SQL code into it. However, I highly recommend setting up a local database as well so that you can follow the 12 factor principles and be able to debug locally: http://12factor.net/

Comment: @Jeff - check out my answer, you do not need to have a local DB or connect with PgAdmin, you can easily do it via command line.

Answer (score 2):

## Django local db import on Heroku on windows

## create backup

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d hawkishfinance > C:\Users\Fauzan\Projects\hawkishfinance.sql
```

## dump on server

```
heroku pg:psql --app hawkishfinance < hawkishfinance.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add run in this command. It will work successfully!

```
heroku pg:psql run --app YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE < updates.sql
```