# How to restore database from one heroku to another heroku database

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have two Heroku application in that from one heroku application - I take a dump. Now I want to restore that database to another heroku application. so How Can I do that?

I try this :

```
heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GREEN_URL "URL" --APP
```

When I run above command then

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL  <---restore---  b013.dump

Retrieving... done
Restoring... done
```

then after when I am checking the database then No records display in the table. 
All table records are blank

So What Should I do?

Please Help Me, Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has step by step documentation on how to do this:

- [Heroku Dev Center: Using PG Backups to Upgrade Heroku Postgres Databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#transfering-databases-between-heroku-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has recently changed their commands around, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508898/how-can-i-import-a-sql-file-into-my-heroku-postgres-database/20511058#20511058) is the newest version of how to do it.