# synching two databases in heroku rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have crm rails application deployed in `heroku` so my database is `postgresql.` I have an iphone app which is using `mysql` database. Now what i need to do is to synch my iphone database with my heroku database.

Can anyone please help me on this is it possible to sync two different databases in heroku

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It all depends on what you mean when you say "different" databases. Are they different in structure, or just data?

Comment: @RichPeck assume that they have same structure but using different technology one is mysql and another one is postgresql. any solution?

Comment: Yeah but you won't like it

Comment: @RichPeck Means is it complex to do Please give your thoughts

Comment: How big is the data-set to be transferred?

Comment: @RichPeck initially contains less data but it might increase. Assume 3 to 4 tables with thousands of records in it

Comment: It's hard to answer a question like that. You should try dumping the DB to sql and importing it not the other side. There will be different problems but it depends on what DB-specific things you used in Postgres.

Comment: One issue definitely is that MySQL doesn't have boolean type so you need to change the SQL file to use tinyint.

Comment: Yep - that's the way I did it back in when we migrated from Heroku - I'll write an answer in a minute for you!

Answer (score 0):

The way we did this was to do it manually

Yep, it's a real pain, but at least you know it's done correctly

--

**Process**

For migrating from Postgres to MYSQL is as follows:

> 1. "Backup" the database using [`pg_backups`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups)
> 2. Download the backup locally
> 3. In MYSQL (we used PHPMyAdmin), create a series of SQL calls to insert the respective data into the correct tables

Migrating from MYSQL to Postgres is, as much as I can determine, a similar process:

> 1. [Download the SQL dumps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html) of your MYSQL DB (I only know how to do this in PHPMyAdmin)
> 2. Configure those files to be "PG" ready
> 3. [Send the SQL to your Heroku postgres db's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508898/how-can-i-import-a-sql-file-into-my-heroku-postgres-database)

--

**Notes**

For specifics, I only have the following:

If you dump from Heroku, you'll not get a traditional SQL file; [you'll receive a `.dump` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export). To change this, you'll need to use [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) in the following way:

```
$ cd c:/your/postgres/install/pg_restore/location
$ pg_restore path_to_your_dump.dump > path_to_your_sql.sql
```

This will give you the ability to "read" the file, uploading to your db & importing as you wish. That's when the fun begins :)

---

**Importing MYSQL**

The way to import MYSQL into a PG db will have to be done manually

Although we've never done this directly (we only migrated *from* PG), there are several things you can do. Firstly, you can use the [PG2MYSQL converter](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php) to give you an idea as to the syntax differences between MYSQL & PG

Then I would perform a "dump" from MYSQL in SQL format. This will give me the data required for PG. This will allow me to insert into my PG database (you might have to do this locally to give you the ability to determine the syntax), from which you can then patch in the MYSQL data

I understand it's not the most elaborate explanation - I hope it gives you some ideas

Comment: Sorry, I have just seen your answer, so that means we need do it manually. can't it be done programmatically