# How to add data from my local postgresql database on heroku's postgresql database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I have a Django project on Heroku. It renders templates, but without any data(that I get from my local postgre database). How can I import data on Heroku database from my local db?

Comment: Have tried the methods mentioned in Heroku documentation? You can find it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#:~:text=Import%20to%20Heroku%20Postgres

Comment: You can follow this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20511058

Comment: `heroku pg:psql --app myappname < updates.sql` doesn't work

Comment: Try this:  `heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL`

Comment: you mean heroku pg:psql --app myappname > heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL ?

Comment: Yes, instead of `--app myappname` use `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: The local psql command could not be located. For help installing psql

Comment: Make sure that `psql` path is listed in your environment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240073/discussion-between---and-vishal-a).

Comment: You can try using WSL to get rid of the EPIPE error that you are getting in Windows.